# Madcatz RAT 3 Mouse issues

Tags: xorg, mouse

I'm having issues with configuring my Madcatz RAT 3 Mouse with Ubuntu 13.04. It's like the mouse is having issues with switching between windows. Movement works fine though.

I have added this to my xorg.conf but it still doesn't work:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier      "Mouse Remap"
    MatchProduct    "Madcatz Mad Catz R.A.T.3 Mouse"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option      "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

Here is some more info.

From xinput list:

```
Madcatz Mad Catz R.A.T.3 Mouse              id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

More details:

```
niel@niel-VPCF13M1E:~$ xinput query-state 13
2 classes :
ButtonClass
    button[1]=up
    button[2]=up
    button[3]=up
    button[4]=up
    button[5]=up
    button[6]=up
    button[7]=up
    button[8]=up
    button[9]=up
    button[10]=down
    button[11]=up
    button[12]=up
    button[13]=up
    button[14]=up
    button[15]=up
    button[16]=up
    button[17]=up
    button[18]=up
ValuatorClass Mode=Relative Proximity=In
    valuator[0]=512
    valuator[1]=762
    valuator[2]=-7
```

cat /proc/bus/input/devices

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0738 Product=1703 Version=0100
N: Name="Madcatz Mad Catz R.A.T.3 Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:05:00.0-1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:05:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input18
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse3 event15 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=3ff0000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=103
B: MSC=10
```

Anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "Mouse Remap"
    MatchProduct    "Madcatz Mad Catz R.A.T.3 Mouse"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option      "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

Comment: Why is this a solution? Please add some explanation.