# RAT 3 Mouse doesn't Left Click

Tags: mouse, 16.04

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 and there is a bug related to my mouse (RAT 3). I cannot use the left click properly. Sometimes I have to open a Window in order to use the mouse in another window.

Comment: We need more information. How is the mouse connected, have you tried plugging into another port. What else have you tried - have you done any research on this?

Comment: Try http://askubuntu.com/questions/92546/cyborg-r-a-t-3-gaming-mouse-stops-working-after-a-while-and-or-misbehaves and http://askubuntu.com/questions/331388/madcatz-rat-3-mouse-issues and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mad_Catz_Mouse

Answer (score 1):

This is a common Ubuntu bug. Try to do this:
Back up the xorg.conf file

```
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.orig
```

May the files doesn't exist. This is not necessary.

Anyway edit the file with `sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf` and paste this:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "Mouse Remap"
MatchProduct "Saitek Cyborg R.A.T.3 Mouse"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit the editor.
 Reboot for functionality!

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mad_Catz_Mouse) from the Arch Linux wiki worked well on my laptop with Ubuntu 16.04.

Here are the most relevant parts:

> #### The Disable Button Solution
>
> The issues are caused by an interaction between R.A.T Mode button and
>   the X Server. To restore proper function, the 'Mode' button must be
>   disabled, as follows:
>
> With root privileges, create and edit the file
>   `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-vmmouse.conf`
>
> Add the following content :
>
> ```
> Section "InputDevice"
>     Identifier     "Mouse0"
>     Driver         "evdev"
>     Option         "Name" "Saitek Cyborg R.A.T.3 Mouse"
>     Option         "Vendor" "06a3"
>     Option         "Product" "0ccc"
>     Option         "Protocol" "auto"
>     Option         "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
>     Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
>     Option         "Buttons" "7"
>     Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
>     Option         "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
>     Option         "Resolution" "3200"
> EndSection
> ```
>
> After restarting your X server, the mouse should be fully functional,
>   including the two lateral buttons.
>
> [...]
>
> #### Manual Button Mapping Fix
>
> Please note that there are two different versions of the R.A.T.3 mouse
>   which are Saitek and Madcatz, this must be input correctly into the
>   "MatchProduct" or you will run into the same issues.
>
> First find out the ID and the Name of the mouse :
>
> ```
> xinput list | grep "id"
> ```
>
> In you should see your mouse labeled as "Madcatz Mad Catz R.A.T.3
>   Mouse" or "Saitek Cyborg R.A.T.3 Mouse". Note the device id number and
>   then input the following command :
>
> ```
> xinput query-state ID
> ```
>
> (Where ID corresponds to the ID number of your mouse)
>
> Note which 'mode' color is currently active (red/blue/purple) and
>   which button numbers correspond to the current 'mode' by being either
>   "up" or "down". Change the mouse 'mode' and and retype the above
>   command, noting which buttons change state to match the 'mode'.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> U = up
> D = down
>                         U U U U U D D U U D D D  U  U 
> Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 0 0 8 9 0 0 0 13 14"
> ```
>
> Where buttons 10, 11, and 12 have been identified as 'mode' buttons,
>   so they can be disabled by with zeros.
>
> When you have identified which button numbers correspond to the mouse
>   'Modes', you should be able to edit your xorg.conf file and disable
>   them by inserting a zero in the appropriate point in the button
>   sequence. Open one of these files in your chosen editor:
>
> ```
> /etc/X11/xorg.conf
> /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-vmmouse.conf
> ```
>
> Create a block that overwrites the mode buttons as follows:
>
> MadCatz R.A.T.3:
>
> ```
> # RAT3 mouse
> Section "InputClass"
>  Identifier "Mouse Remap"
>  MatchProduct "Madcatz Mad Catz R.A.T.3 Mouse"
>  MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
>  Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 0 0 13 14 15 16 17 18"
> EndSection
> ```
>
> This configuration worked for me on my old Saitek Cyborg R.A.T.3:
>
> ```
> # RAT3 mouse
> Section "InputClass"
>  Identifier "Mouse Remap"
>  MatchProduct "Saitek Cyborg R.A.T.3 Mouse"
>  MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
>  Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 0 0 8 9 0 0 0 13 14"
> EndSection
> ```